# JSF2 Composite component link using ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, behavior, composite, composite-component

Here is my (simplified) issue :
I've got a page that is using 2 composite components of mine :
 - CCSelection
 - CCDisplay

In CCSelection, I have a list of values, each one has got a h:commandLink onto.
When clicking on a link, the CCDiaplay component is refreshed using the selected value.
To do this, CCSelection exposes a method attribute that is directly linked on each h:commandLink. The value is given to the method using f:attribute.
In the page backing bean, I've got a method (that is given to CCSelection as an attribute), that sets a member.
CCDisplay gets this value though an cc:attribute via the pages's member's getter.
It works !
Now, I want to ajaxize this behaviour.

I tryed to put an f:ajax for each h:commandLink in CCSelection... but if I put @form or @all in the render attribute, nothing is rendered (but the setter methods are called). If I put the id of the UIComponent (of the Page) to render, I get a nullpointerexception saying that a property is not defined for NamingContainer in CCDisplay. Quite strange because I didn't change anything inside CCDisplay !

I think the solution is to put the f:ajax not inside CCSelection but in Page. 
So there may be 2 ways to achieve this :
 - CCSelection raises an event f:ajax can manage... but how ?
 - Using cc:clientBehaviour for CCSelection. But is it possible to target more that 1 
component (I've got many h:commandLink, but I want only 1 event).
 - Other ways ?


Here is a pseudo code

page.xhtml

```
<myComp:ccSelection actionMethod="#{pageBean.select}"
                    render="#{clientIDHelper.clientId['display']}" />
<h:panelGroup id="diplay" binding="#{clientIDHelper.bindings['display']}">
  <myComp:ccDisplay value="#{pageBean.value}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

To recover the full clientid of the panel containing the ccDiaplay composite component, I use a clientIDMap technic described [here](https://www.xing.com/net/jsf/newsletters-archive-362954/group-newsletter-the-map-hack-26501345/).

PageBean.java

```
private String _value;

public String getValue() { return _value; }
public void setValue(String value) [ _value = value; }

public void select(String value) {
  setValue(value);
}
```

ccSelection.xhtml

```
<cc:interface>
  <cc:attribute method-signature="void selectAction(String)"
                name="actionMethod" />
  <cc:attribute name="render" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
  <t:dataTable value="#{cc.values}"
               var="val"
               ...
               >
    <h:column>
       <t:commandLink actionListener="#{cc.selectionValueListener}"
         <f:ajax render="#{cc.attrs.render}" />
         <f:attribute name="value"
                      value="#{val}" />
       </t:commandLink>
    </h:column>
  </t:dataTable>
</cc:implementation>
```

ccSelection.java

```
public void selectionValueListener() {
  // recover the attribute value
  String value = event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("value");
  // call the callback method of the page
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  MethodExpression method = (MethodExpression) this.getAttributes().get("actionMethod");
  if (method != null)
    method.invoke(context.getELContext(), new Object[] {value});
}
```

I don't think ccDisplay is interressting.

So, if I don't put the f:ajax tag, it works.
When I put the f:ajax with the render pointing to the clientId passed in param, I get an error while loading the page.
If I change the render for @form or @all, the pageBean.select method is called, but ccDisplay is not refreshed.

Comment: If i understand well, you suspect if you warp all your components with the f:ajax tag, it should work, but you dont know what how to handle the event generated by the command link? If that is it i have an idea, you can just warp your existing code with '<f:ajax event="click" execute="#{yourBean.method}">' , in your method, just try to find the way a workaround to handle the event only when desired. If you post a bit of code or pseudo, maybe we could help more.

Comment: In fact, event with f:ajax, the method is called. The issue is the render : CCDisplay is not rendered when using f:ajax when render="@all" or render="@form".<br/>If put the id of the component in the f:ajax render, I get an error when loading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It is solved... but I don't like it very much.
You'll think I'm a fool : I solved the problem by removing the <![CDATA surrounding my scripts !
I've already found some issue using CDATA. I don't know if this is a MyFaces bug or something I do the wrong way like putting many h:outputScript blocks with CDATA in composite components but with CDATA, I get errors or not working. Just removing it, it works !

Answer (score 1):

I think i see a little error in page.xhtml. 
See when you created the component cc:display you said:

```
<cc:attribute method-signature="void selectAction(String)" name="actionMethod" />
```

That means that a parameter is needed.

But when you call it in page.xhtml you do this:

```
<myComp:ccSelection actionMethod="#{pageBean.select}"...
```

And its backing bean method is:

```
public void select(String value) {
  setValue(value);
}
```

As you see the backing bean is correct, but when you call the component in the page, there is no parameter being passed to the bean, and at the end the value is never set.
I think that might be one of the reasons.

To fix it i think you should pass the value some how:

```
<myComp:ccSelection actionMethod="#{pageBean.select(???Selected value

???)}"...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
As far as I Know you can't pass directly parameters like you sugest.
Nevertheless, it is working when f:ajax is not present.
In fact, the parameter is passed by code :
    method.invoke(context.getELContext(), new Object[] {value});

Comment: @boblemar passing parameters to the backingbean via the expresion language is possible, but depends on the app server you use. I use  glassfish v3 and i can do it. Anyway here in this link you can see other alternatives to pass that value: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

Comment: OK. I didn't know. Anyway, I don't think it would have been useful in my case... and I target Tomcat6. Thanks for the link.