# Problem with ajax request, when containing cdata blocks in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have a jsf2 xhtml page:

```
<a4j:commandButton render="blockId" />

<h:panelGroupid="blockId">
    <ui:include src="apage.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

which includes **apage.xhtml**:

```
<html ...>
    <ui:composition>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            //javascript code contains special xml chars
        //]]>
        </script>
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

When command button clicked, this response is being returned for ajax request:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="j_idt4:blockId"><![CDATA[<span id="j_idt4:blockId">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    //javascript code contains special xml chars
//]]>
</script>
<div>
test
</div></span>]]></update><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[-4479406101101075754:7339996762278955153]]></update><extension id="org.richfaces.extension"><render>j_idt4:blockId</render></extension></changes></partial-response>
```

As seen from the response, a top level cdata contains cdata in apage.xhtml. As a result, returned xml is invalid, and couldn't be parsed by the browser.

Is there any way to solve this problem. As a solution, script can be moved to a separate script file, but there are lots of such code upgraded from jsf 1.2, so it is not preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you escape those special Charts using XML entities?

Comment: @Selaron, yes i can, but it is not preffered for readability and ide's js validation.

Comment: Which jsf implementation do you use? And maybe this clarifies it a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7959215/865107

Comment: Mojarra 2.2.18 plus richfaces 4.5.17. I gave up on the problem and moved problematic scripts to separate js files. Thanks for your interest.